# Significato di "non riusciva a dar torto" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Albina non si capacitava. Doveva esserci uno sbaglio. Quella gattarella di sua figlia, quella squaquecchia, quella mezzabotte, chiesta in moglie dal piú bel giovane che si era mai visto a Grottole, quello che tutte volevano e nessuna era mai riuscita ad acchiappare. Invece per qualche misteriosa ragione non c'era nessuno sbaglio, Colino voleva proprio lei e nessun'altra, glielo confermava anche la madre, la sua amica Diodata, cui **non riusciva a dar torto** quando diceva che suo figlio aveva perso il sentimento.

Il significato di "squaquecchia" l'ho trovato su questo [dizionario di vocaboli desueti usati da Francesco Mastriani](http://www.francescomastriani.it/dizionario-desueti-lettera-s/):

> **squaquecchia agg.** • Donna rachitica e bazzuta [N1-71(36)] *Be! donna Squaquecchia, mo non vieni qua fuori! Ti ei consigliata con zio-prete!*

"N1" significa che la definizione proviene dal *Dizionario napoletano* edito da Avalardi (2007).

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/torto2), "dare torto a qualcuno" significa

> non riconoscergli il diritto di fare o dire qualche cosa, affermare che ha agito ingiustamente, che ha detto cosa non vera: *sembrava sicuro del successo, ma i fatti hanno finito col dargli torto*.

Tuttavia, non riesco a capire il senso della frase "non riusciva a dar torto" nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Significa che Albina voleva che Diodata, la madre di Colino, non avesse ragione su quello che le aveva confermato (cioè, che Colino voleva sua figlia come moglie e che "aveva perso il sentimento"), ma non riusciva a smentirla?

Comment: "Dare torto" è il contrario di "Dare ragione", significa non essere d'accordo, ritenere diversamente. "Non dare torto" significa ammettere di essere d'accordo, ma con poca forza, alludendo sovente a una giustificazione non completamente condivisa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuol dire semplicemente che condivideva la stessa opinione. “Non riusciva a dar torto” all'altra donna nel senso che, anche se avesse voluto, non avrebbe trovato argomentazioni per dirle che aveva torto, che sbagliava.

Se A dice qualcosa a B e B dice “Non posso darti torto”, intende che condivide il pensiero di A, con la sfumatura che lo ammette un po' a malincuore. Nella situazione della domanda, non è bello confermare alla madre che il figlio è impazzito, ma Albina la pensa allo stesso modo.